# ios 7 remove viewController from navigationViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, navigationbar

When I do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
[viewControllers addObject:self];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Or like this

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationViewController;
NSMutableArray *arrViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nav.viewControllers];
[arrViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:1];
nav.viewControllers = arrViewControllers;
```

The navigationbar buttons and title are not being updated on IOS 7. So when the user touch one, it makes a crash.
Is there a way to solve this?

It works fine in IOS 6.

Comment: Any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `[nav pushViewController:self animated:YES]` and `[nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Comment: But the problem is that I need to make uiviewcontroller as root. 
I'm using https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels.

this code can solve the problem:
self.sidePanelController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[JACenterViewController alloc] init]];

but i cannot give it an animation.